Find all the ordered triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $b^c = 17+8^a$
Find all the ordered triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $$b^c = 17+8^a$$ with $c>1$
I made $a=1$ and found that $(b,c) = (5,2)$
I made $a=2$ and found $(b,c) \in \{(9,2),(3,4)\}$
then I noticed that if $a$ and $c$ are both even, we get $a=2$.
I tried to work a little more with the parity of $c$ by making everything $\mod 8$ and I got that either $c$ is even or $b \equiv 1 \mod 8$. I also know that even $a$ implies $b \equiv 0 \mod 3$ and clearly that $b$ is odd. None of these tricks solved the problem tho, although exploring even $c$ and odd $a$ does go deep, I got some weird modulo restrictions too big and useless imo and some gcds.
EDIT: as noticed below, $c>1$
EDIT2: apparently there is a theorem that guarantees that for $c>1$, for each $b$ we can only have one value of $c$. Not sure if it helps too much.

Pillai's conjecture would give us all the pairs of perfect powers that differ by exactly $17$.  Not sure whether the case of $n=17$ is settled or not, and of course special technique might let us directly address the case where one of the powers is known to be a power of $8$.

thanks I never heard of that one before, I was thinking that perhaps the generalized Pell's equations might help too

If you allow the case that $c=1$, then trivially every $a$ affords a solution. The problem is only interesting for $c>1$

If $(a,b,c)$ is a solution with $c>1$ then it is one of
$$(1,5,2),\qquad (2,3,4),\qquad (2,9,2),\qquad (3,23,2).$$
I am not aware of any simple proof.

Note: If $c=3d$, then we have $(b^d)^3-(2^a)^3=17$. Since there are no two cubes that differ by $17$, it must be the case that $3\not \mid c$. Thus if $c$ is even, it has the form $6k\pm 2$, and if it is odd, it has the form $6k\pm 1$

FWIW, $b\not \equiv 0,\pm 1 \bmod 7$

You have soluion in the post where $c=1$. Maybe remove these solutions from your solution set.

We can handle the case where  is even thanks to this article (see corollary p. 151), provided in this discussion.
